# How do I delete duplicate rows in SQL Server using the OVER clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here are the columns in my table:

```
Id
EmployeeId
IncidentRecordedById
DateOfIncident
Comments
TypeId
Description
IsAttenIncident
```

I would like to delete duplicate rows where `EmployeeId, DateOfIncident, TypeId` and `Description` are the same - just to clarify - I do want to keep one of them.  I think I should be using the `OVER` clause with `PARTITION`, but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to keep one row of the duplicate-groups you can use `ROW_NUMBER`. In this example i keep the row with the lowest `Id`:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER( 
                  PARTITION BY employeeid, dateofincident, typeid, description 
                  ORDER BY Id ASC), * 
    FROM dbo.TableName
) 
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

use this query without using CTE....

delete a from
(select id,name,place, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id,name,place order by id) row_Count
from dup_table) a
where  a.row_Count >1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query. This has an assumption that you want to keep the latest row and delete the other duplicates.

```
DELETE [YourTable]
FROM [YourTable]  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (  
   SELECT MAX(ID) as RowId 
   FROM [YourTable]   
   GROUP BY EmployeeId, DateOfIncident, TypeId, Description  
) as KeepRows ON  
   [YourTable].ID = KeepRows.RowId  
WHERE  
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```